# SQL statement ignore when attempted to open cursor

Tags: database, plsql, package, procedure

I have an error, "SQL Statement ignored", when I make a spec and body of a package database in PL/SQL.

I wrote this code :

```
PROCEDURE Get_All_Link_Recent_Result
    ( pi_userid        IN  TLMS_CM_RESULT.USERID%TYPE,
      pi_email         IN  TLMS_CM_RESULT.EMAIL%TYPE,
      pi_testid        IN  TLMS_CM_RESULT.TESTID%TYPE,
      po_ret_code      OUT VARCHAR2,
      po_ret_message   OUT VARCHAR2,
      po_ref_cursor    OUT type_cm_result_refcur
    ) IS
    l_userid           TLMS_CM_RESULT.USERID%TYPE;
    l_testid           TLMS_CM_RESULT.TESTID%TYPE;
    BEGIN
      l_userid   :=    pi_userid || 0;
      l_testid   :=    pi_testid || 0;
    OPEN po_ref_cursor

    FOR SELECT * FROM
      TLMS_CM_RESULT WHERE
      USERID LIKE l_userid AND
      TESTID LIKE l_testid AND
      EMAIL = pi_email
     ORDER BY
      USERID;

  po_ret_code := c_err_msg_other;
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
      po_ret_code := c_err_msg_other;
      po_ret_message := SQLERRM;
  END Get_All_Link_Recent_Result;
```

The specific line with the "PL/SQL : SQL Statement ignore" error is the line

```
OPEN po_ref_cursor
```

So, the statements after that, starting with `FOR SELECT * FROM` will also cause an error.

Answer (score 0):

[OPEN CURSOR](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/cursors/open.php) is an independent complete statement. That is, it should ends with a semi colon. In your case semi colon is missing.

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve with your code, I cannot test it. But it is not clear to me why you are opening a cursor without explicitly closing it. Another thing is you seem trying to open implicitly another cursor with [FOR LOOP](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/static.htm#CHDBJBJE). This is not the way to do it.

For example, I would rewrite part of your code as follows::

```
OPEN po_ref_cursor;  --add semi-colon

FOR I IN (SELECT * FROM
  TLMS_CM_RESULT WHERE
  USERID LIKE l_userid AND
  TESTID LIKE l_testid AND
  EMAIL = pi_email
 ORDER BY
  USERID)

LOOP

 po_ret_code := I.c_err_msg_other;

END LOOP;
```

Assuming `c_err_msg_other` is part of your `SELECT` query.